# How to get parent of LI

Tags: javascript

Hi I have a drop down menu by using LI & UL tag .

Eg.

```
<ul>

         <li><a href="#">Parent 1</a>
         <ul>
            <li id = "Child 1"><a href="#">Child 1</a></li>
            <li id = "Child 2"><a href="#">Child 2</a></li>
         </ul>
         </li>
         <li><a href="#">Parent 2</a>
         <ul>
            <li id = "Child 3"><a href="#">Child 3</a></li>
            <li id = "Child 4"><a href="#">Child 4</a></li>
         </ul>
         </li>
</ul>
```

Now my problem is when I click on **Child 1** then in the resultant div should display **Parent 1: Child 1** . How can I achieve this?

Thank You.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<ul>

         <li><a href="#">Parent 1</a>
         <ul>
            <li id = "Child 1"><a href="#" onclick="alert(this.parentNode.parentNode.parentNode.firstChild.innerText + ':' + this.innerText)">Child 1</a></li>
            <li id = "Child 2"><a href="#">Child 2</a></li>
         </ul>
         </li>
         <li><a href="#">Parent 2</a>
         <ul>
            <li id = "Child 3"><a href="#">Child 3</a></li>
            <li id = "Child 4"><a href="#">Child 4</a></li>
         </ul>
         </li>
</ul>
```

The reason for this is that you click the link. So you have to go up throught the ul, to the li, and then get its first client, which is the link containing Parent1.

Comment: This is exactly the solution that I have been searching. However, I would like the parent and child to be displayed as a table for all elements during page load. Could anyhelp help in tweaking this, so there is table with 2 cols -- Parent | Child and the respective values as rows. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2):

```
this.parentElement().getAttribute('id');
```

this will do the trick

where `this` is clicked link

so if the method is

```
function linkClick(obj)
{
    alert(obj.parentElement().getAttribute('id') + ':' + obj.innerHTML);
}
```

all you need to do is attach onclick event to your link

```
<a onclick="linkClick(this); return false;" href="#">Child 1</a>
```